# Need help fixing errors in crystal report formula

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a value in our database that is a string that represents a time value with an example value something like 8.7698 which must be converted to become an actual time. I have started working on this and here is what i came up with so far:

```
stringvar x; //original value, string datatype ex data 9.8765, get value before decimal point
numbervar x2; //convert value before decimal into a double
stringvar xH; //Convert value before decimal back to string for concatenation
stringvar x3; //value after decimal
numbervar x4; //convert value after decimal to double and multiply by .60 for conversion
stringvar xM; //Convert value after decimal back to string for concatenation
x := left({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated}, InStr ({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated},"." ));
x2 := cdbl(x);
x3 := mid({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated}, InStr ({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated},"." ), length({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated}) - InStr ({PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.TimeUpdated},"." ));
x4 := CDbl (x3) * .60;
xH := cstr(x2);
xM := cstr(x4);
xH + ":" + xM;
```

It says No errors when I check it, but the report is failing to run from within our software (Sage 100) and I believe there is an issue with this formula. Can anyone see where I may have messed up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's back up and try to simplify this formula since it's difficult to understand it as it stands. You've got a lot of unnecessary variables and typecasts that can be cut out completely. Try something like this instead:

```
local stringvar timeString := '9.8765'; //Example value

local stringvar hr := split(timeString,'.')[1]; //the hour value
local stringvar min := split(timeString,'.')[2]; //the fractional hour to convert to mins

//the below line concatenates the hour and the newly calculated minutes
//  which is just the first two digits with necessary leading/trailing zeros
hr + ':' + totext(tonumber(min) * 0.6, '00')[1 to 2]
```

If you're not getting any error messages when you save the formula, it may not even be the cause of the report failure. In that case, you'll need to provide some more details about what happens and what debugging steps you took.

Comment: What does the value 9.8765 supposed to show as the answer? I get 9.52. Not sure if it is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I knew I was probably going about it the hard way, thank you Ryan for your elegant solution and for the others who chimed in to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: Below formula is used assuming number before decimal is hour and number after decimal is minute. IF this is not your requirement ignore the solution
```

Use below formula

```
 Local NumberVar a;
Local NumberVar b;
Local NumberVar c;
Local StringVar d;


c:=RoundUp(ToNumber("8.669"),2);
a:=ToNumber(Split ('8.669',"." )[1]);
b:=ToNumber(Split ('8.669',"." )[2]);
d:=Split(CStr(ToNumber(Split(Totext(c),".")[2])/60))[1];
if(ToNumber(Split(Totext(c),".")[2])<60)
then 
ToText(a,0)+":"+Split(ToText(c),".")[2]
else
ToText(a+ToNumber(d),0)+":"+Split(Totext(c/60),".")[2];
```